# Create Console Web API Project

Tags: c#, web, console

Here is my Code

```
static async Task myapiget(HttpClient cons)
        {

            try
            {
                using (cons)
                {
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback= (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                    HttpResponseMessage res = await cons.GetAsync("api/employees/GetAllemployees/");
                    //HttpResponseMessage res = await cons.GetAsync("9-21-2023/SPO");
                    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {



                        EmployeeDet emp = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeDet>();

                        //string JsonData = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        //List<EmployeeDet> employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeDet>>(JsonData);

                        

                        Console.WriteLine("\n");

                        Console.WriteLine("----------------calling get Operation------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("ID   First Name      Last Name       Gender      Salary");
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
                     //  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t\t{4}", emp.Empid, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, emp.Gender, emp.Salary);
                        Console.ReadLine();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No Record Exist");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Check Whether API is running or NOT");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

AND I'M FACING THIS TYPE OF ERROR

```
>  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)\
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)\
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at ConsumeWebAPIControl.Program.<myapiget>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\WebAPI\ConsumeWebAPIControl\ConsumeWebAPIControl\Program.cs:line 47
```

ON THIS LINE

`EmployeeDet emp = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeDet>();` is line py

I TRY LOT'S OF CODE BUT DIDN'T SOLVE THE PROBLEM

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: While you're editing your question, can you add in the actual exception? All that's the currently is the stack trace.

Comment: "GetAllemployees" would make me expect some sort of Collection but you seem to deserialize only a singular object. So, my suspicion is that the payload is not what you are expecting.

Comment: Oh, and do not `using` an `HttpClient` ...